# Laravel 5.1 Accessing Collection key / value

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1 (PHP), I have a call as follows:

```
$CableSizes = CableType::getCableSizeList(1);
```

Which returns the following collection (as I understand). To show its contents I run `dd($CableSizes);`:

```
array:21 [▼
  0 => {#208 ▼
    +"cable_specification_id": 1
    +"cable_conductor_size_mm": "0.50"
  }
  1 => {#209 ▶}
  2 => {#210 ▶}
  3 => {#211 ▶}
  4 => {#212 ▶}
  5 => {#213 ▶}
  6 => {#214 ▶}
]
```

I can access the first element by doing `dd($CableSizes[0]);`. Ho do I access the contents on the first element, and retrieve `cable_conductor_size` (or `0.50` in the example above). I am trying variations of `dd($CableSizes[0].cable_conductor_size);` but all returning errors.

I cannot seem to ask this question to Google so I get an example to view. How do I access this value?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it like you would any other object:

```
dd($CableSizes[0]->cable_conductor_size);
```

Also: it’s convention for variables to being with lowercase letters, i.e. `$cableSizes`. Classes should be named camel-case with the first letter uppercase though (`CableSize`).